# Java Count the x's in a given string recusively

Tags: java, string, recursion

Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of lowercase 'x' chars in the string.

countX("xxhixx") → 4

countX("xhixhix") → 3

countX("hi") → 0

my attempt:

```
public int countX(String str) {
  int sum = 1;
  if(str.length()-1==0){
    return sum;
  }
  else{
    if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
      return sum+countX(str.substring(1));

    }
    if(str.charAt(0)!='x'){
      return countX(str.substring(1));
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error message: `This method must return a result of type int.`
Not even sure if my base-case is correct. Any hints?

Comment: You have no return outside of the conditionals.

Comment: *You* can tell that `==` and `!=` are mutually exclusive, but the compiler can't. Use `else` instead of `!=`.

Comment: @chrylis: Strictly speaking, mutual exclusivity doesn't really matter here. What matters is that that the two ifs exhaust all possibilities. They could overlap -- and therefore not be mutually exclusive -- and still be fine. Conversely, they could be mutually exclusive but fail to cover all possibilities.

Comment: @NPE True enough. In this case, of course, they do, but the compiler still doesn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a requirement that every code path through the function must return a value, and the compiler is being a little bit overly pedantic on you:

```
if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
  return sum+countX(str.substring(1));
}
if(str.charAt(0)!='x'){
  return countX(str.substring(1));
}
// <--- there's no return value here
```

Arguably, the compiler *could* figure out that the two if statements exhaust all possibilities, but it doesn't.

One way to help the compiler along is by rephrasing the two ifs as a single if-else:

```
if(str.charAt(0)=='x') {
  return sum+countX(str.substring(1));
} else {
  return countX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to get rid of this 'int sum'? Because the code works only if there are any x's in the string i put in.

Comment: @DerDieDasEhochWas: Think carefully about your base case. Your current code can never return zero. Also, it doesn't handle strings of length one correctly. I think with these hints you can solve it. :-)

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @DerDieDasEhochWas: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a fall through instead of explicitly having `if/else`, which in some cases can confuse the compiler

```
public static int countX(final String str) {
    //base case
    if(str.length() == 0) {
       return 0;
    }
    else if(str.length() == 1) {
        return str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    //recursive step
    return str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 1 + countX(str.substring(1)) : countX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: If you pass an empty string to this version, bad things will happen because the base case assumes at least one character.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice. But what if I put in the empty string? If I do, I get an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not all code paths had returns (from a dumb compiler point of view).  It also seems wrong to start sum at one.  Consider:

```
public int countX(String str) {
  if(str.length()==0){
    return 0;
  } else if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
    return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
  } else {
    assert str.charAt(0)!='x';
    return countX(str.substring(1));
  }
}
```

Or:

```
public int countX(String str) {
  if(str.length()==0){
    return 0;
  }
  if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
    return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
  }
  assert str.charAt(0)!='x';
  return countX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Many ways to fry a fish:

```
public int countX(String str) {
  return str.isEmpty() ? 0 : (
    (str.charAt(0)=='x' ? 1 : 0)
    + countX(str.substring(1))
  );
}
```

Want even more succinct and less readable?

```
public int countX(String str) {
  return str.isEmpty()?0:countX(str.substring(1))+str.charAt(0)=='x'?1:0;
}
```

Sorry, I'm having fun trending toward a code obfuscation toy.

Comment: number 1 and 2 do not work for all cases. Number 3 does indeed work, but I've  never heard of assert though. Number 4 scared me, so I didn't test it.

Comment: Number 1 and 2 checked string length incorrectly, fixed.  I was trying to take it iteratively away from your original code to then show other options.  Just examples I typed - did you actually run these?

Comment: About assertions: as the programmer, we know a certain condition should be logically true under specific conditions.  We can capture this knowledge, in a way, and have it checked while in debugging modes through `assert` statements.  The expression after `assert` must evaluate to `true` and will only be ran when assertions are enabled (usually debug/develop time but not production).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
public int countX(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  if(str.length()-1!=0){
    sum = countX(str.substring(1));
    if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
      sum += 1;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Your problem is that in some case, there's no return.
One way to avoid this is by using a single return instruction at the end of your method, or you can simply add some else cases to your code like this:

```
  [...]
  else{
    if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
      return sum+countX(str.substring(1));
    }else{
      return countX(str.substring(1));
    }
  }
  [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int countX(String str) {
  if (str.length() == 0) return 0;
  int sum = 0;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'x') sum = sum + 1;
  return sum + countX(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: You don't need `sum` variable. You can replace it with single line: `return (str.charAt(0) == 'x' ? 1 : 0) + countX(str.substring(1));`